# Algebras of adjointable operators on dense subspaces of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $W$ be a **proper** dense subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ (e.g., the space of smooth square-integrable functions on the unit interval $[0, 1]$). Let $BA(W)$ denote the set of bounded, adjointable operators on the (incomplete) inner product space $W$, i.e., the bounded linear operators $T$ on $H$ such that $W$ is both $T$-invariant and $T^*$-invariant. This is (canonically) a unital *-subalgebra of $B(H)$. Is it dense in $B(H)$ in the operator norm topology? If so, what is a simple proof?

Comment: In case $W$ is the linear span (no closure) of the canonical orthonormal basis in $\ell^2$, the question becomes whether or not every bounded operator can be approximated by operators whose matrix has finite rows and columns.  This should not be too hard to determine but so far I can't seem to find a proof either way.  This might be related to Voiculescu's quasi-diagonal operators.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $\mathcal{H}$ is a separable Hilbert space. For $W\subset \mathcal{H},$ let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ denote an orthonormal basis of $W,$ i.e. a maximal orthonormal collection of elements. Since $W$ is dense, the set $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis in $\mathcal{H}.$
Let $W_0$ denote the linear span of $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Then $W_0\subset W.$

We will consider the family $\mathcal{A}$ of all bounded operators $T,$ such that $T(W_0)\subset W_0$ and $T^*(W_0)\subset W_0.$ We claim that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $B(\mathcal{H}).$

Fix $0\neq A\in B(\mathcal{H}).$ Let $P_n$ denote the orthogonal projection on ${\rm span}\,\{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n\}$ and $Q_n=I-P_n.$  For a fixed $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $k_n\ge n$ such that
$$\|Q_{k_n}Ae_n\|\le 2^{-n/2}\varepsilon,\quad  \|Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\|\le 2^{-n/2}\varepsilon,\quad n\ge 1$$
Consider the operator $R$ given by
$$Rx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,e_n\rangle Q_{k_n}Ae_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x, Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\rangle e_n$$
We claim that $R$ is bounded. Indeed, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,e_n\rangle |\|Q_{k_n}Ae_n\|\le \|x\|\left (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|Q_{k_n}Ae_n\|^2\right )^{1/2}\le \varepsilon\,\|x\|$$
and
$$\displaylines{\left \|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x, Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\rangle e_n\right \|=\left (\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x, Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\rangle |^2\right )^{1/2}\\ \le 
\|x\|\,\left (\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \|Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\|^2\right )^{1/2} \le \varepsilon\,\|x\|}
$$
Let $B=A-R.$ Then $\|A-B\|\le 2\varepsilon. $ Moreover $B(W_0)\subset W_0.$ Indeed
$$\displaylines{Be_m=Ae_m-Re_m=Ae_m-Q_{k_m}Ae_m-\sum_{n=1}^m \langle e_m, Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\rangle e_n\\ =P_{k_m}Ae_m-\sum_{n=1}^m \langle e_m, Q_{k_n}A^*e_n\rangle e_n\in W_0}$$
Observe that
$$B^*=A^* -R^*=A^*- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x, Q_{k_n}Ae_n\rangle e_n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,e_n\rangle  Q_{k_n}A^*e_n$$ Hence $B^*(W_0)\subset W_0.$

**Remark** The above is a partial answer, because the operators, which leave $W_0$ invariant do not need to leave the space $W$ invariant.

Comment: Nice!  Well, your answer is complete for the special case in which $W=W_0$, as I mentioned in a comment above.  Another interesting case is when $W$ is the range of an injective compact operator $U:K\to H$.  In this case you can prove that for any $A\in \mathcal A$, there is some $B\in B(K)$ such that $AU=UB$.  I'm not sure what to do afterwards, but this is perhaps a start.

Comment: @Thanks. I would test the problem for example on $W$ consisting of $x$ such that $$\sum| \langle x,e_n\rangle |^2n^2<\infty $$ That's a particular case of the range of a compact diagonal operator.